# In Symfony: How to exclude module from filters chain

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, filtering

I have a custom filter do some stuff.

And I want specific module to be not included in the filter chain. In another word, for this module I want my custom filter not execute on this module and executing for other modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use custom filter too and inside this filter you can retrieve the current module:

```
<?php

class customFilter extends sfFilter
{
  public function execute ($filterChain)
  {
    $context = $this->getContext();

    if ('moduleName' == $context->getModuleName())
    {
      // jump to the next filter
      return $filterChain->execute();
    }

    // other stuff
  }
}
```

Otherwise, you can also give the excluded module inside the `filters.yml` file:

```
customFilter:
  class: customFilter
  param:
    module_excluded: moduleName
```

And inside the class:

```
<?php

class customFilter extends sfFilter
{
  public function execute ($filterChain)
  {
    $context = $this->getContext();

    if ($this->getParameter('module_excluded') == $context->getModuleName())
    {
      // jump to the next filter
      return $filterChain->execute();
    }

    // other stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: Great, that work for me but there is a little modifications to make this code work ---> inside filters.yml ---> it's "param:" not "params:"